# Show all group members

Tags: command-line

I am still fairly new with Ubuntu and I forgot the command to show all the users of a group. How do you show all the users in all thee groups?

Comment: sorry, do you want all users in all groups, or all users in a particular group?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-all-members-of-a-group/

Comment: is this what you are looking for: `cat /etc/group`

Answer (score 6):

`getent` (comes with `libc-bin`) is what you're looking for.

And you want to parse the `group` database (`/etc/group` and/or alike) e.g.:

```
getent group adm
```

will get you the relevant entry for group `adm`, including the group membership info.

The fields are:

```
<group_name>:<group_password>:<group_id>:<members>
```

If you just want the usernames of the members:

```
getent group adm | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

The added advantage of `getent` is that it would fetch the data from network too, if configured on `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

On my system:

```
% getent group adm
adm:x:4:syslog,foobar

% getent group adm | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
syslog,foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new. Thats the way I am doing it:
Change to the /etc folder

```
cd /etc
```

then open the file group with an editor of your choice (e.g. nano)

```
nano group
```

here you will see a list of all groups followed by the group members